# trun the output of arbitrary function into a list

Tags: python

I have a function. It prints strings. How can I best collect these strings in a list?

i.e.

```
def FUN(a):
...
    print(somestrings)
```

Comment: Why don't you rewrite the function to return the string, instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
x = list()

x.append(strings1)  # use a loop of some sort to append your strings
x.append(strings2)
. 
.
.
x.append(stringsN)

return x
```

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily change `sys.stdout` to a custom class:

```
import sys

def fun(a,b):
    print(a)
    print(b)

class Catcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.res = []
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self
    def write(self, chars):
        self.res.append(chars)
    def call(self, fun, *args, **kwargs):
        fun(*args, **kwargs)
        sys.stdout = self.stdout
        return self.res

print(Catcher().call(fun, "hello", b="world!"))

=> ['hello', '\n', 'world!', '\n']
```